# How to Create Linked List with Sentinel value

Tags: c, struct, while-loop, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to create a function that creates Linked List Based on Sentinel Value **-1** and returns beginning address of that list.

```
struct Node* Create_List(){
struct Node *head,*temp;
head=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
printf("Enter a value: ");
scanf("%d",&head->val);
if(head->val==-1){
    head=NULL;
}
else{
    temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    head->next=temp;
    while(1){
        temp->next=NULL;    
        printf("Enter a value: ");
        scanf("%d",&temp->val);
        if(temp->val==-1){
            temp=NULL;              
            return head;            
        }
        else{
            temp->next=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));   
            temp=temp->next;
        }           
    }
}
return head;
```

}

When I enter **-1** in the beginning it returns empty list this case is okay. But when i add second node, third node and so on **-1** appears on final node on the list but i don't want that.

Comment: Can you clarify? You mean the final node you add has `val` -1 (because that's what your code does: `if(temp->val==-1)`), or do you mean every node has `val` -1?

Comment: @BurnsBA final node has.

Answer (score 2):

Your function definition does not make sense. For example there are memory leaks as in this code snippet

```
head=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
printf("Enter a value: ");
scanf("%d",&head->val);
if(head->val==-1){
    head=NULL;
}
```

That is at first a memory is allocated and its address is assigned to the pointer head and then if the user entered -1 the pointer is overwritten by the value NULL. So the allocated memory was not freed.

Also the while loop always adds a node with the value -1 to the list.

The function can be defined the following way

```
struct Node* Create_List( void )
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    struct Node **current = &head;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a value of the node (-1 - exit): " );

        int val;

        if ( scanf( "%d", &val ) != 1 || val == -1 ) break;

        *current = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );

        ( *current )->val = val;
        ( *current )->next = NULL;

        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: `Create_List` returns null every time?

Comment: @Neil No, it returns the head node that is not null if data was entered.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Node* Create_List(){
struct Node *head,*temp;
int val;
printf("Enter a value: ");
scanf("%d",&val);
if(val==-1){
    head=NULL;
}
else{
    head=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    head->val=val;
    head->next=NULL;
    temp=head;
while(val!=-1){
        printf("Enter a value: ");
        scanf("%d",&val);
        if(val!=-1){
            temp->next=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp=temp->next;
            temp->val=val;
        }
        else{
            temp->next=NULL;
            return head;
        }
    }
}
return head;
```

}